# How to succesfully install d3 as Laravel dependency and bind it to a constant

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, d3.js, npm

I'm trying to get d3 working in my Laravel project. I used the following 
[tutorial](https://www.giacomodebidda.com/how-to-import-d3-plugins-with-webpack) as guide.

I've created a new Laravel project, modified some stuff (switched to Foundation instead of bootstrap), and installed the required d3 modules.

I did this by installing the required dependencies using npm.

```
npm install d3-array d3-drag d3-force d3-selection
npm run dev
```

Next, i toyed around a lot with variations of the following code in app.js:

```
import { select, event } from 'd3-selection';
import { drag } from 'd3-drag';
import { range } from 'd3-array';
import { forceLink, forceSimulation, forceManyBody } from 'd3-force';

const d3 = Object.assign(
    {},
    {
        select,
        event,
        drag,
        range,
        forceLink,
        forceSimulation,
        forceManyBody,
    },
)
```

I also tried installing d3 and including everything, but never could i access the d3 object in my browser console (Firefox, Chromium).

```
>>d3
ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
```

I tried some console.log() which did get shown, so somehow d3 doesn't bind to the constant variable.

EDIT:
I also do [vendor extraction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#vendor-extraction).

Comment: `const d3 = ...` is not the same as `window.d3 = ...`

Answer (score 0):

[flame](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346367/flame) thank you, using `window.d3 = ...` instead of `const d3 = ...` solved my problem.